# Selenium webdriver - How to click the next button until Not able to find Next button in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Responsive website where it contains 36 buttons .At first glance we can only able to see 12 buttons and I need to validate their text values which I know how to do that .But problem is I need to click next button until it is not visible. So how can I do it with selenium in c#.

Also while clicking next we need to store text for the button in a list or array so i can add all the lists in a new list and do comparison.

Look at below code which i tried

```
while (respRightNav.Displayed)
        {
            IList<IWebElement> sportsBtn = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".sports-buttons-responsive>ul li[class='sport-button']"));
            foreach (var item in sportsBtn)
            {
                string btnText = item.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
                if (btnText == btnText.ToUpper())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sports Button : " + btnText + "  is In Upper Case");
                }
                else
                {
                    Assert.Fail("Sports Button Text is not Upper Case for : " + btnText);
                }
            }

            respRightNav.Click();
            if (respRightNav.Displayed.Equals(false))
            {
                break;
            }
```

Now above is working but i'm stuck at when Next button is not available  I still need to run above foreach loop for getting text (  if (respRightNav.Displayed.Equals(false))). means i need to run Foreach loop

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Posting some of your code would help someone here; help you.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi Please check my updated code and let me know how can i go and run foreach before breaking the method ?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the ".Displayed" value with a `while` loop:

```c#
IWebElement button;
while((button = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[.='Next']")).Displayed) {
    button.Click();
    ...

}
```

Or with `FindElementsByXPath` in a single call matching the visible element:

```c#
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> buttons;
while((buttons = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//input[.='Next' and not(contains(@class,'none'))]")).Count > 0) {
    buttons[0].Click();
    ...

}
```

Comment: @Florernt can you please see updated question and suggest  me answer.